# Regex matcher not giving expected result. Not matching number properly

Tags: java, regex

I cannot understand why 2nd group is giving me only 0. I expect 3000. And do point me to a resource where I can understand better.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches {

   public static void main( String args[] ) {
      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
      String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );//?
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3) );
      }else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to make the first `*` quantifier non-greedy. change it to `*?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precise the pattern, add `QT` before the `\d` pattern, or use `.*?` instead of the first `.*` to get as few chars as possible.

```
String pattern = "(.*QT)(\\d+)(.*)";
```

or

```
String pattern = "(.*?)(\\d+)(.*)";
```

will do. See a [Java demo](http://ideone.com/CfLeyv).

The `(.*QT)(\\d+)(.*)` will match and capture into Group 1 any 0+ chars other than line  break chars, as many as possible, up to the last occurrence of `QT` (followed with the subsequent subpatterns), then will match and capture 1+ digits into Group 2, and then will match and capture into Group 3 the rest of the line.

The `.*?` in the alternative pattern will matchand capture into Group 1 any 0+ chars other than line  break chars, as *few* as possible, up to the first chunk of 1 or more digits.

You may also use a simpler pattern like `String pattern = "QT(\\d+)";` to get all digits after `QT`, and the result will be in Group 1 then (you won't have the text before and after the number).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for anwering. What if the string is "ABCD1234DEFG", and I want to extract only 1234.

Comment: `String pattern = "\\d+";` if you want to use `Pattern#find()`. Or just `s=s.replaceAll("\\D+", "");`, see http://ideone.com/DAgVKe.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` quantifier will try to match *as many as possible*, because it is a `greedy` quantifier.
You can make it non-greedy (lazy) by changing it to `*?`

Then, your regex will become :

```
(.*?)(\d+)(.*)
```

And you will match `3000` in the 2nd capturing group.

Here is [a regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/YdR2wI/1)

Comment: Thanks Seblor for answering. What does the '?' actually do in this regex? As far I know it used to match 0 or 1 occurences.I like to know what is the significance in this regex.

Comment: I makes the `*` quantifier non-greedy (lazy). It works the same for the `+` quantifier too.

Comment: What is meant by non-greedy ( lazy )?

Comment: Instead of trying to match as many as possible, il will stop matching as soon as the rest of the regex can match.